# How can I write this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Spent a while on this still cant quite get it. I have some rows in a table like this:

```
uuid, pos (R|S|N), number (1-10), account (string), xtype (string)
```

A unique row is identified by `uuid, pos,` number

I am trying to write a query that can find occurrences of:

- same uuid where

  - account = x, pos = R, number = 1
  - account = x, pos = S, number = 1
  - no occurrences of pos N
  - pos R has only a row with number 1, no other occurrences of pos R for this uuid

Hope I have provided enough info, please let me know if you need any more.

Comment: Can you post the query you are trying?

Comment: sample data as DDL + DML and desired results would help answering this (and any other) sql question. Also, what version of sql server are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for uuids the records of which match certain conditions. So you aggregate per uuid (i.e. `GROUP BY`).

```
select uuid
from mytable
group by uuid
having count(case when account = 'x' and pos = 'R' and number = 1 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when account = 'x' and pos = 'S' and number = 1 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when pos = 'N' then 1 end) = 0
   and count(case when pos = 'R' and number <> 1 then 1 end) = 0;
```

(Well actually with `uuid` + `pos` being unique, you can remove the last condition, as it is included in the first one and you can change `> 0` to `= 1` if you find this clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after a query to find instances of uuid values that have various rows in your table satisfying all four conditions?

You could either use CTE:

```
with c1 (uuid)
    as (select uuid from myTable where account = 'x' and pos = 'R' and number = 1),
    c2 (uuid)
    as (select uuid from myTable where account = 'x' and pos = 'S' and number = 1),
    c3 (uuid)
    as (select uuid from myTable where pos = 'N'),
    c4 (uuid)
    as (select uuid from myTable where pos = 'R' and number <> 1)

select distinct myTable.uuid 
from myTable
    inner join c1 on myTable.uuid = c1.uuid
    inner join c2 on myTable.uuid = c2.uuid
    left join c3 on myTable.uuid = c3.uuid
    left join c4 on myTable.uuid = c4.uuid
where c3.uuid IS NULL and c4.uuid IS NULL
```

Or you could use `exists`:

```
select distinct uuid from myTable t
where exists (select 1 from myTable where uuid = t.uuid and account = 'x' and pos = 'R' and number = 1)
  and exists (select 1 from myTable where uuid = t.uuid and account = 'x' and pos = 'S' and number = 1)
  and not exists (select 1 from myTable where uuid = t.uuid and pos = 'N')
  and not exists (select 1 from myTable where uuid = t.uuid and pos = 'R' and number <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using conditional aggregation and the over clause:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE 
(
    uuid int,
    pos char(1),
    Number tinyint,
    Account varchar(3),
    xtype char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'R', 1, 'abc', 'a'),
(1, 'S', 1, 'def', 'b'),
(1, 'N', 1, 'ghi', 'c'),
(1, 'R', 2, 'jkl', 'd'),
(2, 'R', 1, 'mno', 'e'),
(2, 'S', 1, 'pqr', 'f'),
(2, 'N', 1, 'stu', 'g'),
(3, 'R', 1, 'vwx', 'h'),
(3, 'S', 1, 'yz', 'i')
```

The CTE will contain columns telling us if the conditions are met:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  uuId, 
            pos,
            Number,
            Account,
            xtype,
            SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 'R' AND Number > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY uuId) As WrongR,
            SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY uuId) As NExists,
            SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 'R' AND Number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY uuId) As RightR,
            SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 'S' AND Number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY uuId) As RightS
    FROM @T
)
```

Query the cte:

```
SELECT  uuId, 
        pos,
        Number,
        Account,
        xtype
FROM CTE
WHERE WrongR = 0
AND NExists = 0
AND RightR = 1
AND RightS = 1
```

Results:

```
uuId    pos     Number  Account     xtype
3       R       1       vwx         h
3       S       1       yz          i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select uuid from table where account = x and pos = R and number  = 1
intersect 
select uuid from table where account = x and pos = S and number  = 1
except 
select uuid from table where                 pos = N 
except 
select uuid from table where                 pos = R and number <> 1
```